# Sending large zip file over REST

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

In my spring boot application, I have stored a zip file as a BLOB in the database.

Currently I have written an api which fetches the zip file converts it into base64 format and sends it as a response.

Issue I am facing is that since my zip file can me in megabytes as well it would take a lot of time to send the data to the client and there could be some data mismatch as well.

The zip file is basically a template file which as html css and js folder and files.

What is the recommend way to send a large zip file?

P.S. - I cannot save the zip file in the file system. It has to be read from the db itself.And in the db it is stored as a BLOB

Comment: My question is related to how can we handle sending a large zip filethrough rest.
Here the zip file is stored as a byte array and I am able to convert it into base64 and send the data to the client side.But i want to optimize the solution so that there is no mismatch in database.

Comment: Have you read the most upvoted answer of that question?